# While loop doesn't check for existing words in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I'm new here, forgive me if I don't put things in the right order :)

I was trying to start with the basic game where you have to type a word that is 4 letters long and everything was fine until, I introduced new statement to check if the word has already been used and added to a new list. As of right now, code saves the word into a list for 1 run and then removes it. 
P.s i was trying to make it like a function, but function gives me errors or endless loops.

```
while True:
    used_words: List[str] = []
    word: str = raw_input("Type 4 letter word: ")
    if len(word) == 4 and word not in used_words:
        used_words.append(word)
        print("good job, try another word")
    elif word in used_words:
        print("word already exists")
    elif len(word) > 4 or len(word) < 4:
        print("word is not 4 letters long")
    else:
        continue
```

my expectation is to run the code where every valid word would be saved in a list and checked for existence in that list. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see the [Markdown Editing Help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for code formatting tips. In python it's very important to preserve your indentation. In pasting your code and attempting to fix it manually, you've introduced indentation errors. (Which someone has just fixed for you, but that can be dangerous too, so best to do make sure you get it right yourself.)

Comment: `raw_input` in Python 3?

Comment: The `if` and the first two `elif` cover all possible cases (A and B, no A, no B), so you will never enter the last `else`. The loop will therefore run forever

Comment: Be aware that Python doesn't use raw_input() anymore so change your code to use input() instead, as per @Ingvar's answer

Comment: @glibdud, thanks for the notice, I will read the help page to avoid this mistake in the future .

Answer (score 1):

You recreate `used_words` each iteration and initialize it with empty list, move it outside loop:

```
used_words = []
while True:
    word = input("Type 4 letter word: ")
    if len(word) == 4 and word not in used_words:
        used_words.append(word)
        print("good job, try another word")
    elif word in used_words:
        print("word already exists")
    elif len(word) != 4:
        print("word is not 4 letters long")
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help! If you don't mind me asking, maybe you could show me how to implement this into a function?

Comment: @Eurostyle https://pastebin.com/BijKTjkq please accept this answer if it was helpful :)

Comment: Thank you once again, I figured my mistake was the incorrect placement of an empty list. I'm glad I came to the right place. Hoping to be like you one day and return a favor! :)